# Office 2010 user defined Color theme as default

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office-2010

I have created a new colour theme that represents our companies standard colours and want to define it as the default. The default colour theme  is Office. How do I define my company theme as the default theme?

Comment: What have you researched and/or tried so far? Have you [searched](https://www.google.com/search?q=office+2010+custom+color+scheme) how to do it?

Comment: I have discovered that if you save the xml file with the colour theme to the office templates directory the theme is always available for selection from the possible colour themes across all office applications, It requires a manual selection / check that the theme is the active one.